# Python: Dot product of each vector in two lists of vectors

Tags: python

Say I have two lists containing vector:

```
A = [(1,1,1), (0,1,1)]
B = [(1,0,1), (1,0,0)]
```

I hope to perform dot product between each vector elementwise so that the output is

```
C = [2, 0]
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In pure Python, try a nested list/generator comprehension:

```
>>> [sum(ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b))
...  for a, b in zip(A, B)]
[2, 0]
```

or with numpy, you can do an element-wise product of the 2-dimensional arrays, followed by a sum along each row:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.multiply(A, B).sum(1)
array([2, 0])
```

Note that the numpy solution will only work if all vectors are the same length – each list of vectors is implicitly converted into a two-dimensional matrix.

Answer (score 20):

The fastest method here is using [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)

```py
out = numpy.einsum('ij, ij->i', A, B)
```

It outperforms the multiply-add version by a factor of 2; the list comprehension version is *a few hundred* times slower.

[image]

---

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy
import perfplot

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (numpy.random.rand(n, 3), numpy.random.rand(n, 3)),
    kernels=[
        lambda data: numpy.einsum("ij, ij->i", data[0], data[1]),
        lambda data: numpy.multiply(data[0], data[1]).sum(1),
        lambda data: [
            sum(ai * bi for ai, bi in zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(data[0], data[1])
        ],
    ],
    labels=["einsum", "multiply+sum", "sum+zip"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(18)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
```

Comment: This is really good and fast. I love the elegance too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use zipping, summing, and list comprehensions for a fancy one-liner:

```
A = [(1,1,1), (0,1,1)]
B = [(1,0,1), (1,0,0)]
C = [sum(i*j for i, j in zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
print(C)  # [2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[sum([y*z for y, z in zip(*x)]) for x in zip(A, B)]
```

This produces:

```
[2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dot_product(vector_a, vector_b):
    vector_c = (vector_a[0]*vector_b[0],vector_a[1]*vector_b[1],vector_a[2]*vector_b[2]) #vector multiplication
    return sum(vector_c) #sum of each chord in the new vector
c = [dot_product(a[0],a[1]), dot_product(b[0],b[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using `numpy.dot`:

```py
dots_prods = [numpy.dot(a, b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

### However, still slow compared to @nico-schlömer's `einsum` method:

[image]